# Window "on desktop"

Tags: c#, wpf

I've been using [Rainlendar](http://www.rainlendar.net) for some time and I noticed that it has an option to put the window "on desktop". It's like a bottomMost window (as against topmost).

How could I do this on a WPF app?

Thanks

Comment: **Warning** The accepted answer suggests that you call SetParent to create a child of the Desktop. If you do this, you cause the Win32 Window Manager to synchronize the input queue of the Desktop to your child window, this is a *bad thing* - [Raymond Chen explains why.](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/24/79212.aspx) Basically, if your window hangs or blocks (say with a MessageBox) you will lock up your desktop.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My answer is in terms of the Win32 API, not specific to WPF (and probably requiring P/Invoke from C#):

Rainlendar has two options:

- "On Desktop", it becomes a child of the Explorer desktop window ("Program Manager"). You could achieve this with the [SetParent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633541(VS.85).aspx) API.
- "On Bottom" is what you describe - its windows stay at the bottom of the Z-order, just in front of the desktop. It's easy enough to put them there to begin with (see [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545(VS.85).aspx)) - the trick is to stop them coming to the front when clicked. I would suggest handling the [WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632653(VS.85).aspx) message.

Comment: Thanks Hugh, I have the "on bottom" part working, going to try with SetParant now.

Basically "on desktop" is "on bottom" without minimizing right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at with "without minimizing", but if you use MS Spy++ to examine the window tree (with Rainlendar running) you will hopefully see what I mean.

Answer (score 9):

This is what I used so the window is always "on bottom":

```
   using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Interop;
```

...

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X,
   int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
const UInt32 SWP_NOACTIVATE = 0x0010;

static readonly IntPtr HWND_BOTTOM = new IntPtr(1);

public static void SetBottom(Window window)
{
    IntPtr hWnd = new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle;
    SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I was trying to do the same...
i've used a lot of ideas arround, but i was able to to it and prevent the flickering.

I managed to override WndProc, used one setwindowpos before to put it in the background, and another to prevent it from getting the focus...

```
    const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
    const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
    const UInt32 SWP_NOACTIVATE = 0x0010;
    const UInt32 SWP_NOZORDER = 0x0004;
    const int WM_ACTIVATEAPP = 0x001C;
    const int WM_ACTIVATE = 0x0006;
    const int WM_SETFOCUS = 0x0007;
    static readonly IntPtr HWND_BOTTOM = new IntPtr(1);
    const int WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING = 0x0046;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X,
       int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr DeferWindowPos(IntPtr hWinPosInfo, IntPtr hWnd,
       IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr BeginDeferWindowPos(int nNumWindows);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool EndDeferWindowPos(IntPtr hWinPosInfo);

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IntPtr hWnd = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
        SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOACTIVATE);

        IntPtr windowHandle = (new WindowInteropHelper(this)).Handle;
        HwndSource src = HwndSource.FromHwnd(windowHandle);
        src.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(WndProc));
    }

    private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        if (msg == WM_SETFOCUS)
        {
            IntPtr hWnd = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
            SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
            handled = true;
        }
        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        IntPtr windowHandle = (new WindowInteropHelper(this)).Handle;
        HwndSource src = HwndSource.FromHwnd(windowHandle);
        src.RemoveHook(new HwndSourceHook(this.WndProc));
    }
```

Comment: For future reference, this code will only work with WPF apps with `using System.Windows.Interop;`

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106101/winforms-equivalent-of-wpf-windowinterophelper-hwndsource-hwndsourcehook) for more info

Answer (score 4):

Based on the answers of [HrejWaltz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15499185/291823) and [James M](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39150799/291823), I want to provide a modified solution that intercepts and modifies incoming `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` messages by setting the `SWP_NOZORDER` flag instead of calling `SetWindowPos` everytime a `WM_SETFOCUS` message is received.

The class offers attached properties to directly add to a WPF Window using `WindowSinker.AlwaysOnBottom="True"`.

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interop;

public class WindowSinker
{
    #region Windows API

    // ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming

    private const int WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING = 0x0046;

    private const uint SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
    private const uint SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
    private const uint SWP_NOZORDER = 0x0004;
    private const uint SWP_NOACTIVATE = 0x0010;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct WINDOWPOS
    {
        public IntPtr hwnd;
        public IntPtr hwndInsertAfter;
        public int x;
        public int y;
        public int cx;
        public int cy;
        public uint flags;
    }

    private static readonly IntPtr HWND_BOTTOM = new IntPtr(1);

    // ReSharper restore InconsistentNaming

    #endregion

    #region WindowSinker

    private readonly Window window;
    private bool disposed;

    public WindowSinker(Window window)
    {
        this.window = window;

        if (window.IsLoaded)
        {
            OnWindowLoaded(window, null);
        }
        else
        {
            window.Loaded += OnWindowLoaded;
        }

        window.Closing += OnWindowClosing;
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposed) return;

        window.Loaded -= OnWindowLoaded;
        window.Closing -= OnWindowClosing;

        disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    ~WindowSinker()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Event Handlers

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int x, int y, int cx, int cy,
        uint uFlags);

    private void OnWindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SetWindowPos(new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle, HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOACTIVATE);

        var source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle);
        source?.AddHook(WndProc);
    }

    private void OnWindowClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        var source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle);
        source?.RemoveHook(WndProc);
    }

    private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        if (msg == WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING)
        {
            var windowPos = Marshal.PtrToStructure<WINDOWPOS>(lParam);
            windowPos.flags |= SWP_NOZORDER;
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(windowPos, lParam, false);
        }

        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Attached Properties

    private static readonly DependencyProperty SinkerProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Sinker",
        typeof(WindowSinker),
        typeof(WindowSinker),
        null);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AlwaysOnBottomProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "AlwaysOnBottom",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(WindowSinker),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnAlwaysOnBottomChanged));

    public static WindowSinker GetSinker(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (WindowSinker) d.GetValue(SinkerProperty);
    }

    private static void SetSinker(DependencyObject d, WindowSinker value)
    {
        d.SetValue(SinkerProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetAlwaysOnBottom(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (bool) d.GetValue(AlwaysOnBottomProperty);
    }

    public static void SetAlwaysOnBottom(DependencyObject d, bool value)
    {
        d.SetValue(AlwaysOnBottomProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnAlwaysOnBottomChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is Window window)
        {
            if ((bool) e.NewValue)
            {
                SetSinker(window, new WindowSinker(window));
            }
            else
            {
                GetSinker(window)?.Dispose();
                SetSinker(window, null);
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The OnDesktop version that Im using:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

public static void SetOnDesktop(Window window)
{
    IntPtr hWnd = new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle;         
    IntPtr hWndProgMan = FindWindow("Progman", "Program Manager");
    SetParent(hWnd, hWndProgMan);
}
```

I was having some trouble finding the Program Manager window, but Kimmo, the creator from Rainlendar gave me a link to the code:

http://www.ipi.fi/~rainy/legacy.html

If anybody needs more detail just look in library/rainwindow.cpp for the function SetWindowZPos.

Answer (score 3):

The attached property version of @HrejWaltz's answer:

**Update (12/28/2016)**

```
public class WindowSinker
{
    #region Properties

    const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
    const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
    const UInt32 SWP_NOACTIVATE = 0x0010;
    const UInt32 SWP_NOZORDER = 0x0004;
    const int WM_ACTIVATEAPP = 0x001C;
    const int WM_ACTIVATE = 0x0006;
    const int WM_SETFOCUS = 0x0007;
    const int WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING = 0x0046;

    static readonly IntPtr HWND_BOTTOM = new IntPtr(1);

    Window Window = null;

    #endregion

    #region WindowSinker

    public WindowSinker(Window Window)
    {
        this.Window = Window;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr DeferWindowPos(IntPtr hWinPosInfo, IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr BeginDeferWindowPos(int nNumWindows);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool EndDeferWindowPos(IntPtr hWinPosInfo);

    void OnClosing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        var Handle = (new WindowInteropHelper(Window)).Handle;

        var Source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(Handle);
        Source.RemoveHook(new HwndSourceHook(WndProc));
    }

    void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var Hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(Window).Handle;
        SetWindowPos(Hwnd, HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOACTIVATE);

        var Handle = (new WindowInteropHelper(Window)).Handle;

        var Source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(Handle);
        Source.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(WndProc));
    }

    IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        if (msg == WM_SETFOCUS)
        {
            hWnd = new WindowInteropHelper(Window).Handle;
            SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
            handled = true;
        }
        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    public void Sink()
    {
        Window.Loaded += OnLoaded;
        Window.Closing += OnClosing;
    }

    public void Unsink()
    {
        Window.Loaded -= OnLoaded;
        Window.Closing -= OnClosing;
    }

    #endregion
}

public static class WindowExtensions
{
    #region Always On Bottom

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SinkerProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Sinker", typeof(WindowSinker), typeof(WindowExtensions), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
    public static WindowSinker GetSinker(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (WindowSinker)obj.GetValue(SinkerProperty);
    }
    public static void SetSinker(DependencyObject obj, WindowSinker value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(SinkerProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AlwaysOnBottomProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("AlwaysOnBottom", typeof(bool), typeof(WindowExtensions), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnAlwaysOnBottomChanged));
    public static bool GetAlwaysOnBottom(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(AlwaysOnBottomProperty);
    }
    public static void SetAlwaysOnBottom(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(AlwaysOnBottomProperty, value);
    }
    static void OnAlwaysOnBottomChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var Window = sender as Window;
        if (Window != null)
        {
            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            {
                var Sinker = new WindowSinker(Window);
                Sinker.Sink();
                SetSinker(Window, Sinker);
            }
            else
            {
                var Sinker = GetSinker(Window);
                Sinker.Unsink();
                SetSinker(Window, null);
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: can u add the sample, how to use this?