# Make aplication always on Bottom (pinned to desktop, behind all other apps) in C++/WinAPI

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have some C++/WinAPI application.

I want it to "replace" Windows 7 desktop (so it will be displayed **always on bottom** of all applications, just before desktop. Moreover, when user will click somewhere on my application, I want to receive it (in a normal way) but my application **must stay on bottom**.

I have found related post for C#, but I didn't find it as a solution to my problem:

[How to make 'always-on-bottom'-window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527950/how-to-make-always-on-bottom-window)

Additional question: can I make so for other than mine (I have .exe only) application? By it I mean that my application will set other application on bottom like I described.

Comment: What did you not understand about that answer?

Comment: First of all it is not complete (marked anserw is in spirit of "DONT DO IT!", quote: "this is a bad thing", and the second anserw is "just speculation"). Second, it was for C#, third: maybe somebody will post a sample c++ code/function here . Btw you wrote "possible duplicate in comment", when I wrote in my post and linked to that topic before -_-' ;)

Comment: Both of you are trying to accomplish the same thing. The answer posted there is for general WinAPI, which can be used in either language. That's pretty much a duplicate for me. Even the title matches very closely.

Comment: The accepted answer does suggest what you need to do as well as giving advice on what not to do - see the second paragraph. One of the other answers also links to an additional question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365094/window-on-desktop) which has answers which elaborate on the same solution. As @RedX has pointed out, it is irrelevant that the answer is for C# because the solution uses WinAPI.