# How to create a StickyNotes-like window?

Tags: delphi, desktop-application, desktop, delphi-xe7

How to create a window (form) that is similar to Sticky Notes?

The main characteristic that I need:

- It never gets minimized (Win+D / Win + W)

Other characteristics:

- It always remains under other windows
- No taskbar button
- Transparency (if possible)

Setting form's parent to ProjMan almost works! The problem is that the form is not semi-transparent when I do so (alpha blend/transparency is ignored):

```
 hWindow := FindWindow(NIL, PChar('Program Manager'));        // this might be a bad idea. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527950/how-to-make-always-on-bottom-window
 if hWindow <> 0 then Form1.ParentWindow := hWindow;
```

I was thinking (yes, I know it is a dirty hack) I could put code in a 1000ms timer to restore the window if it was minimized but it won't work when Win+D is pressed. Looks like windows are not actually minimized when Win+D is pressed.

Comment: The link you include in your comment was closed as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/365094 - it didn't help either?

Comment: You can always resort to WinAPI calls such as `SetWindowLong` or similar.

Comment: Very broad without [mcve]. There are certainly existing questions on: hiding the taskbar button; setting transparency; and controlling z-order. As for preventing a window from being minimised on `Win+D`, personally I would consider that hostile and unacceptable behaviour. _Make sure your uninstall feature works!_

Comment: As for preventing a window from being minimised on Win+D @CraigYoung - That happens when you don't offer your users a Settings window. My programs are always fully customizable. So, the user will easily change the behavior.

Comment: @CraigYoung-If you have problems understanding the question, let me know