# WPF imagecontrol and media element

Tags: c#, wpf, image, desktop, mediaelement

I wanna put a media element to inside a image control . For example like this ;

```
   <Image>
      <MediaElement
    </Image>
```

And after do this I wanna save this image to my computer as a image . Is something this possible accorting to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you trying to do is impossible on many levels.
First of all, [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.aspx) control does not support direct content so you can`t put any other control inside it. And this control is used to display some image, it is not image itself.

Second, [MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.aspx) is used to contain video or audio. How can you save audio or video as image (image that makes sense anyways)?

So the answer to your question is: **no**, it`s not possible.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was so clearly answer for me. I understood. I'm newbie in WPF world . I wanted to trying an extreme thought. I want to do showing a movie or video as a wallpaper instead of an image in Windows 8. It may be an absurd idea to you but I wanted to try . Is there any other way making this project according to you? Is this possible ?

Comment: @captainblack, it is possible. You can try to make app with [borderless window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstyle.aspx) or Window with custom [control template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.template.aspx) that plays video in loop, is maximized and stays [always on bottom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365094/window-on-desktop). You don\`t need images for that, only video. And it won\`t replace wallpaper, it will be on top of it, but can look like background.