# How to pin a WPF application window to the desktop, it should not minimize on Window + D (Show desktop)

Tags: .net, wpf

I have created a simple digital clock on WPF and I want it to behave like a widget which we used to have in windows 7. So for that, I have done all necessary changes like
1. Made window background transparent
2. Made the window draggable by clicking anywhere on the window
3. Made the window hidden from the taskbar and active task list (Alt + Tab)

Just the one thing which I could not achieve till now is
4. Permanently pinning the window to the desktop, it should even be visible when we click on 'Show desktop' or Window + D

Comment: you can bring it up when it's minimized by attaching to window state change event

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Window "on desktop"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365094/window-on-desktop)