# Is there a way to keep a WPF window always on top of a fullscreen app?

Tags: wpf, windows, overlay

I'm trying to create an overlay that should still be shown while fullscreen apps are running (i.e. games).

Right now, this is what I have:

```cs
public partial class MainView : Window
{
    public const int WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x00000020;
    public const int GWL_EXSTYLE = (-20);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index, int newStyle);

    public MainView(IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //IsHitTestVisible = false;
        Loaded += (sender, args) =>
        {
            // Get this window's handle
            IntPtr hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;

            // Change the extended window style to include WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
            int extendedStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);

            SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, extendedStyle | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);
        };
        DataContext = provider.GetRequiredService<MainViewModel>();
    }
}
```

```xml
<Window
        ...
        WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize"
        Left="1670" Top="0" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance viewModels:MainViewModel}"
        mc:Ignorable="d" AllowsTransparency="True" Topmost="True"
        Title="MainView" Height="450" Width="250">
    <Window.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Opacity="0.25" Color="DarkGray"></SolidColorBrush>
    </Window.Background>
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I'm using `Topmost=True` to ensure the window is always visible, and `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` to let mouse clicks "fall through" to the window below. This is working perfectly for windowed and borderless windowed apps. However, when starting a dedicated fullscreen app, like a game, the window loses focus and is hidden by the fullscreen app.

If I run my overlaid app and, before the window is instanced, I quickly alt-tab to the fullscreen app, the overlay stays on top of the fullscreen app, until I alt-tab out of the fullscreen app and back. Then, the previous behavior is observed.

Is there a way to keep a window as "topmost" over fullscreen apps?

I've tried the solution from [C# WPF Overlay for fullscreen applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66512492), to no avail. In fact, using the sinker makes the window disappear once I alt-tab from *any* app, windowed or not.

Something I noticed is that whenever I switch to a fullscreen app, it forces becoming "topmost", but, if I set `topmost` to `false` then to `true` back again (I did it with a keyboard hook, so that I don't need to focus on the window to use a shortcut to set its properties), it pops right back to its place - until I alt tab back to the desktop again.

I've also found this: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-make-a-window-always-on-top-even-when-fullscreen-game-is-running-by-Qt. If this is true, then how do Steam/Discord/GeForce experience overlays work?

Not even https://github.com/lolp1/Overlay.NET works on fullscreen apps.

Comment: No. Other applications can also set topmost and the when the user clicks on the game and it gets focus, it will win over yours because user interaction takes priority. You can try upping your apps priority by signing it and using a manifest as described in one of the lower scoring answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050426/wpf-always-on-top

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549004/fullscreen-directx-overlay-yes-again-c-sharp

Comment: Don't implement something can generate an infinite loop of focus, lose focus, re focus.

Comment: @Andy So clicking on a windowed / borderless fullscreen app doesn't grab focus? Because when running my app with a borderless fullscreen app, even when I click on the game window, my overlay still sits on top of the game.

I wonder how do NVidia/Steam/Discord overlays work on fullscreen apps.

Comment: Depends what the game does. Topmost might work or it, might not.

Comment: Any ideas on how Steam or Discord overlays work? I suspect they have different solutions for borderless windowed and dedicated fullscreen apps, but I couldn't find any info on those